# How to go about containing a float within a div with variable space

Tags: css, html, css-float, absolute

I've got a series of divs ('group') with text in them, and in the bottom corner a floated div ('toggle'). The code I have works if the text within 'group' is a certain length, but since the space within varies between divs, the floated 'toggle' position does as well. I could set the 'toggle' div as an absolutely positioned element within the 'group', but then text doesn't wrap around it (and I need the text to respect the borders of 'toggle'). So, how can I go about positioning 'toggle' in the lower-right corner of my 'group' div, regardless of size? Should I just make a bunch of @media calls, or is there a better way to accomplish this?  Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="group">
<p class="grouptitle"><a href="#">Name of group goes here</a></p>
<p class="grouptext">Brief description of group goes here. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit,sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut  nisl ut aliquip isl isi enim ad</p>
<div class="toggle"></div>
</div>
```

And here's my CSS:

```
.group {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  min-height: 300px;
  min-width: 300px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 12px;
  background-color: cyan;
  vertical-align: top; }

.toggle {
  float: right;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: green;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-right: -10px;
  margin-top: 32px; }
```

Thanks for reading!

EDIT: [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b2LxU/3/). I need to make it so the green div stays in the bottom corner of the cyan div regardless of the text within the cyan div, and with the text wrapping around the green div.

Comment: Woops yeah sorry posted the SASS, let me fix that

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to accomplish.  Is this not what you're after? http://jsfiddle.net/XpK93/

Comment: Here's a fiddle demonstrating my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/b2LxU/3/   As you can see, I need some way to position the green div at the bottom corner regardless of the text within the cyan div, while respecting the borders of the green div. It sounds silly, but could I absolutely position the green div while maintaining it's float status (so the text wraps around the green div)?

Comment: So you're not using absolute positioning because you don't want the text to flow under the toggle box?

Comment: Correct. Is there some way around this with absolute positioning?

Comment: I don't think so.  One solution is to add padding to your `.group`, but that'll offset all of the text.  It won't flow into the toggle box, but it won't span the entire width of the container.

Comment: `float` removes `position` status unfortunately. `absolute` will work fine, considering it's parent is `relative`.

Comment: @NicholasHazel Right, but that doesn't solve the wrapping problem

Comment: It's a pretty niche requirement anyway.  How are you going to deal with a scenario is which the text is longer than the container?

Comment: Dude, this is irrelevant to the question. *Deleting all comments but this*

Comment: Thanks for brainstorming with me guys, one possible solution I'm currently playing around with is adding padding like monners suggested combined with negative margin on the text. I'll post what I come up with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm reading your issue correctly, I think that using:

```
position: absolute;
bottom:0;
right:0;
```

Would solve it. Here's a fiddle to show you what I'm talking about. - http://jsfiddle.net/fishgraphics/b2LxU/13/

Comment: Been a while since I looked at this, but that solution, while solving the problem of positioning 'toggle', still suffers from the problem of  the text not respecting the boundary/not wrapping around 'toggle'. [Heres your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b2LxU/18/) with a modification to show the problem. 
Ultimately, I got around these issues on the project I was working on by adding a png image that faded to the background color of the 'groups' div adjacent and to the left of the 'toggle', thereby making the text fade out. Hacky, but worked for me at the time.

Comment: @Ber If you were to take the height away from the "group" div, then you shouldn't run into that issue. http://jsfiddle.net/fishgraphics/b2LxU/19/